# Elisp, can I pull-in (provide) a function & variable from a library without changing library?

Tags: org-mode, elisp

I.e
In elisp, from inside an .el file, you can make functions global like this:
`(provide 'org-pomodoro)`

Now, in my personal .emacs, I would like to access (pull in?) a function that's internal to a library (org-pomodoro) but without actually changing org-pomodoro (as I'm not the maintainer of the package).

e.g I want to access `org-pomodoro-finish` myself to implement the functionality of switching between a task and continuing the pomodoro in another task.

For this I also need to be able to access a count-variable.  (e.g like ~~org-pomodoro-time)

**[edit]**
The solution below works quite well. I can just evaluate (org-pomodoro-finished) and a pomodoro is finished ahead of time. I can then write my own function that will be listed in M-x for convienience.

Thank you so much, this opens many doors for me.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Emacs Lisp doesn't have a module system, and all symbols are global.

What `provide` does is simply putting its parameter onto the list of loaded modules.  `require` checks the list, and ensures that the given module has been loaded.

So in order to access the `org-pomodoro-finish` function, you just need to ensure that the `org-pomodoro` module has been loaded:

```
(require 'org-pomodoro)
(org-pomodoro-finish ...)
```

Comment: I'm slightly confused. So Elisp has no module system... so just pull in this module and everything will be fine?

Comment: I apologize for my elips ignorance. Thank you for help :-D.

Comment: @PythonNut, yes.  Emacs Lisp doesn't have a module system, but it has a primitive notion of module -- a module is just a file ending in a call to `provide`.

Comment: @jch I see. I suppose I'm confusing a module system with the existence of modules. Thanks!

Comment: I wouldn't use the word "module". Instead, the model here is that whenever a source file is loaded, its definitions are added to the one, shared namespace everything can see. That's why the naming convention is so important, and e.g. you see everything from org named with a `org-` prefix. The `require` is only to make sure it's loaded, not to give you visibility or access. If it _happened_ to already be loaded, you would already be able to access its definitions, even without the `require`.